# Combining sequences in Rx

Tags: c#-4.0, system.reactive

I am trying to apply Rx methods to an existing application that uses Tasks and Events. Thanks to a previous question I made significant headway but now have a scenario that I am not sure how to tackle in Rx so I thought I would ask for advice.

Here's the situation:

Step 1) Retrieve list of items each containing an identifier. This is a finite list which will complete (e.g. web service call returning data). I have this as an IObservable at the moment.

Step 2) For each unique identifier from Step 1) retrieve secondary information from a different source. It is possible and more efficient to get this secondary info for multiple identifiers in a single call (e.g a second web service).

Step 3) Combine the information into a single IObservable

I do not want to make a call in step 2 for something I have already requested.

I'm sure there must be a really elegant solution using Rx but I'm not familiar enough yet with Rx to nail it down. Any ideas would be welcome.

Regards
Alan

Comment: For clarity, can you provide as a minimum, an example Item type, the return type in step 1 (not clear if it's `IObservable<Item>` or `IObservable<List<Item>>`), the method signature of the call to get secondary information, with an example of what the results look like, and in step 3, what the final results should look like. I can provide a solution with this information, but as it stands without clear example input/output this question is too ambiguous.

Comment: I didn't want to over influence any potential replies but using the old-age stock ticker analogy. Step 1) could be getting non-unique stock codes from a file/database and finding related static information about each stock (e.g company name etc.). Probably a list - I'm not sure what's best. Step 2) Provide result of 1) to get a stream of live price updates subscribing to multiple stocks in one go without repeating a subscription. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so - I'm cueing off the comment you made *"Being new to Rx..."* in Paul's answer.

Your problem is quite easy if the initial list of results comes back all at once in a single result as a `List<T>`. So I'm going assume it doesn't - it comes back as a stream of items which may include repeated information.

#### Scenario

Here's the contrived scenario: a service returns a stream of company names, which may have repeated names. Using a secondary service, you need to look up the stock symbol for each company, but just once. You want to make the look-up in batches for efficiency if possible. For each company you want to subscribe to it's prices using it's stock symbol from a third service.

You ultimately want to convert the stream of company names into a single stream containing the combined price ticker of all companies.

I'm not sure how practical what follows is in your case or in general, but it was an interesting diversion none the less, and hopefully educational!

#### Mocked Up Services

Here are some mocked-up service implementations to call - which you should be able to dump into the `Program` class of a Console app to try out. There's a lot to set up to mock this out, but the solution at the bottom which uses all this is really quite short:

First, here's a `StockInfo` type to capture company stock information, any a mini-database of examples:

```
public class StockInfo
{
    public static List<StockInfo> StockDatabase = new List<StockInfo> {
        new StockInfo { Symbol = "MSFT", Name = "Microsoft" },    
        new StockInfo { Symbol = "GOOG", Name = "Google" },
        new StockInfo { Symbol = "APPL", Name = "Apple" },
        new StockInfo { Symbol = "YHOO", Name = "Yahoo" },
        new StockInfo { Symbol = "DELL", Name = "Dell" },
    };

    public string Symbol { get; set; }        
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Here's a service method that take a list of names and returns a list of `StockInfo` for them:

```
public static Task<List<StockInfo>> GetStockInfo(IList<string> symbols)
{
    return Task.Run(() => 
    {
        var results = from s in symbols
                      join i in StockInfo.StockDatabase
                      on s equals i.Name
                      select i;

        return results.ToList();                  
    });
}
```

Here's a type to hold a stock price for a given `StockInfo`:

```
public class StockPrice
{
    public StockInfo StockInfo { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return StockInfo.Symbol + ":" + Price;
    }
}
```

This service call returns stream of prices at random intervals for a given `StockInfo`. Note we dump out the subscription request to the console; if our solution works, you'll never see a subscription request for the same company more than once:

```
private static Random random = new Random();

public static IObservable<StockPrice> GetPrices(StockInfo stockInfo)
{    
    return Observable.Create<StockPrice>(o =>
    {      
        Console.WriteLine("Subscribed for " + stockInfo.Symbol);

        return Scheduler.Default.ScheduleAsync(
            (Func<IScheduler, CancellationToken, Task>)(
            async (ctrl, ct) =>
        {
            double price = random.Next(1, 10);
            while(true)
            {
                await ctrl.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(random.NextDouble() * 10));
                price += Math.Round(random.NextDouble() - 0.5d, 2);
                var stockPrice = new StockPrice {
                    StockInfo = stockInfo,
                    Price = price
                };
                o.OnNext(stockPrice);
            };  
        }));                       
    });
}
```

Here's the initial service call to gradually return some company names, with a few duplicates (this is all so contrived - I mean why wouldn't you do the de-duping on the service side!):

```
public static IObservable<string> GetStockNames()
{
    var exampleResults = new List<string> {
        "Microsoft",
        "Google",
        "Apple",
        "Microsoft",
        "Google",
        "Yahoo",
        "Microsoft",
        "Apple",
        "Apple",
        "Dell"
    };

    return exampleResults.ToObservable()
        .Zip(Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)), (x, _) => x);
}
```

#### Solution

With all that setup on board, we can proceed to a solution (add this to your Console App's `Main` method):

First, we decide on our batching - we will batch up to 3 companies, but not wait for more than 5 seconds for them to arrive.

```
const int batchSize = 3;
var maxWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
```

Now we get our stream of company names:

```
var names = GetStockNames();
```

We use Distinct() to extract the first instance of each name. We then use `Buffer` to batch up the names, taking at most `batchSize` names or waiting for at most `maxWait` timespan; whichever comes first (line 2). We then project each buffer (a list) into a lookup to our stock info service and covert the resulting list into a stream of individual `StockInfo` objects. (lines 3-5), flattening the whole thing into an `IObservable<StockInfo>`. This will then be a unique stream of `StockInfo` items:

```
var uniqueCompanies = names.Distinct()
                    .Buffer(maxWait, batchSize)      
                    .SelectMany(nameBatch => GetStockInfo(nameBatch)
                                            .ToObservable()
                                            .SelectMany(info => info));
```

Finally we can project each StockInfo into a stream of prices, and flatten the lot to get a single combined price stream:

```
var getPrices = uniqueCompanies.SelectMany(info => GetPrices(info));

getPrices.Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);
```

Output will be random data at random intervals, something like:

```
Subscribed for MSFT
Subscribed for GOOG
Subscribed for APPL
GOOG:6.37
MSFT:7.05
GOOG:7.12
APPL:5.34
Subscribed for YHOO
Subscribed for DELL
MSFT:7.35
YHOO:8.2
```

Hope that's of use!

Comment: James - I'll need to digest this and apply it in my application. The reason for not removing duplicates is that there are other properties on the equivalent of the StockNames request which are not unique, although the equivalent price request only uses the duplicated key. I was trying to simplify my solution into an example that was easier to understand and could be useful to others learning Rx. I see huge potential for Rx in what I am doing.

Comment: OK, in that case note there is an overload of `Distinct` that accepts an `IEqualityComparer` so you can provide a customized notion of what constitutes a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Tada:

```
GetAListOfThings()
    .SelectMany(list => GetSecondaryInformation(list)
        .Select(secInfo => new { list, secInfo }));
```

Comment: The "I do not want to make a call in step 2 for something I have already requested" requirement makes this a tricky problem. Paul, do you have a solution for this?

Comment: I agree - but I want more clarity before answering (see OP comments). It's quite easy to pull out the unique items with grouping, but I'm not sure whether we are processing a list or a stream of items.

Comment: Paul's idea spot on*. From his naming, I can infer that GetAListOfThings() returns a sequence of IObservable<IList<T>> that has a single value i.e. the List of things. This single list is then passed to the `GetSecondaryInformation` method. The responsibility of not making duplicate calls is encapsulated in the `GetSecondaryInformation` method. *I think it needs to be turned into query comprehension syntax for the `list` variable to be available in the `Select`

Comment: It doesn't need to be in query syntax to use the outer parameter

Comment: Being new to Rx I'm trying to grasp whether I need to wait for the whole of Step 1) to complete (i.e. get a complete list) before I can make the request to Step 2) which is more of a continuous stream or if there's a better way (maybe batching) to do this given a better knowledge of Rx.

Comment: @AlanRutter It depends on the underlying implementation of your web service. If the service itself doesn't stream data, Rx can't really make it stream data (at least in a way that's actually better, it can only fake it).